# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. in android

Tags: java, android

I am new in android programming. when I am running my app it shows this kind of error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

it is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "uz.ums"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'

}
```

I cleaned project and rebuild but this didn't help to me.What can you suggest to me! Thanks beforehand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one

```
defaultConfig {        
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: it says duplicate error: 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/widget/PopupMenuCompat.class

Comment: Try. Check if you have the android-support-v4.jar in your libs folder, simply delete and build project.